# Hangfire with Cosmos DB: Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, hangfire

I have Hangfire that use Cosmos DB as database. When I choose Retries tab I get error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 68d632fc-8c5a-4624-80a5-7e9bc0d252f0; Reason: ({
"Errors": [
"Resource Not Found. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"
]
});)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

CosmosException: Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 68d632fc-8c5a-4624-80a5-7e9bc0d252f0; Reason: ({
"Errors": [
"Resource Not Found. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"
]
});
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

When I try to make select statement on Cosmos DB to get items with `key='retries'`:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.key = 'retries' and c.value = 'b7ad3971-8647-4a29-a2a7-412e2da41527'
```

I get error in Cosmos DB:

```
Failed to query item for container hangfire:
 Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":46,"end":51},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'value'."}]}

ActivityId: 4bc1d85a-4ea6-47c2-95d0-81bdde78f389, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0
```

When I make select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.key = 'retries'
```

I can see result without error. Error occurs when I add `AND c.value=...` to the where clause.
I can't open retries tab on `Hangfire dashboard`.
Json in Cosmos looks like:

```
{
        "key": "retries",
        "value": "b7ad3971-8647-4a29-a2a7-412e2da41527",
        "score": 0,
        "created_on": 1611580578,
        "type": 7,
        "id": "b04c5c23-d324-45e1-acce-cdd2379c4073",
        "_rid": "QO5WANzKkljY-gEAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/QO5WAA==/colls/QO5WANzKklg=/docs/QO5WANzKkljY-gEAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"2d01ed73-0000-0100-0000-600ec4a30000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1611580579
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `value` is a keyword. Please try the following query and it should work:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.key = 'retries' and c["value"] = 'b7ad3971-8647-4a29-a2a7-412e2da41527'
```